# load a specific element from an ajax loaded page

Tags: jquery

So...um, how can I load a specific DIV from a page loaded via ajax?

I have this working

```
$.get(url,function(content){
    //ajax content here

});
```

there is a div called `#content` from the page being loaded. I want to load that div into my div called `#wrap` on the main page.

I was thinking something like this maybe

```
$("#wrap").load($(content).find("#content"));
```

Comment: So you are loading an entire page from the ajax get, and you want to pull one div out of that, and put the content inside another?

Comment: yes!.... um I mean, yes thats what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
$.post('THE LINK',
    function(data)
    {
        $('#wrap').html($(data).select('#content').html());
    }
);
```

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/P77Ev/

Comment: hmmm, your fiddle differs from your answer

Comment: Because jsfiddle has /echo/html to post back html, I use that to give a functioning answer (check the ajax tab on the left).

Comment: quick question, I think I know why my page isn't being loaded correctly. In the url page I have jquery make some elements on the fly that I want to target in the AJAX call. How can I get that markup to be created just like it would if I accessed the second page independently?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, ajax (to the best of my knowledge) doesn't run javascript on the called page.  You could look at the eval command, or use iframes instead.

Comment: Looking at the jQuery source, there is no execution of remote javascript on the second page.  So, yes, you would need to use an invisible iFrame to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

Load can use a selector...

```
$('#wrap').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Pulled directly from the jQuery Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

[`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) already does that for you (look under ***'Loading Page Fragments'***). In your case, get rid of the call to `$.get()` and use the following instead:

```
$("#wrap").load(url + ' #content');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#wrap").load(url + " #content", data, function(text, data, xhr){alert("success!");});
```