# Replace div after jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an ajax post request to authenticate users, this script replies with a full webpage. Within the response if successful there is a div called `#logged`.

What I would like to do, is check if the requested result contains `logged` and then replace content within the corresponding `#primary-content` div. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried so far? Someone will probably get you an answer, but you learn a lot more by trying it yourself, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check if the response contains a div called logged, then get the content of a div called 'primary-content' contained in the response string.

Pretty simple really... Once your `ajax` object `readyState` has reached `4`.

Just do this... presuming your ajax or data object is called `ajax`.

```
var logged = $("#logged", $(ajax.responseText)); //grab the logged element from the ajax obj
//check that the logged element exists
if(typeof logged !== "undefined"){
    //replace the content
    $("#primary-content").html(logged.contents());
}
```

Sources

- [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript)
- [Grabbing Content from Other Pages with Ajax and jQuery](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/09/grabbing-content-from-other-pages-with-ajax-and-jquery/)
- [load a specific element from an ajax loaded page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526599/load-a-specific-element-from-an-ajax-loaded-page)
- [parse html string with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704679/parse-html-string-with-jquery)

Comment: ajax responseText contains a full webpage, not only the primary-content div or logged div. I want to work with selectors, using as context the result string. How can I do it?

Comment: There you go, I've edited my answer :P other options would to get your webpage is response with some JSON (much more manageable that way).

Comment: convert the data in the response to .html() then use it like an object. var y = someResponse.html(); y.contains("x");

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to check if ajaresult contains "logged " ? 
var primaryContent = '';

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    var loggedDiv = null;
    loggedDiv  = $(data).find('div#logged');
    if(loggedDiv != null && loggedDiv != undefined){
      primaryContent  = $(data).find('div#primary-content').html();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Ehm, the problem is that response string contains a full webpage. I want to check if the response contains a div called logged, then get the content of a div called 'primary-content' contained in the response string.